# In python plots, what does "1e8" mean in reference to the y-axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
return np.exp(x)

x=np.linspace(-20,20,201)
```

I am plotting **e^x** in python, and when I create equally spaced points with linspace, the y-axis seems to be doing funny things.  When I choose:

```
x = np.linspace(-20,20,201)
```

the y-axis doesn't appear correct, the function is supposed to be crossing the y-axis at 1 when x = 0.  However it doesn't appear to be so in the plot. On top of the y-axis it says le8. What does that mean?

However, When I try:

```
x = np.linspace(0,3,201)
```

The plot crosses the y-axis at 1 when x = 0 which is correct.  However, the plot doesn't have "le8" on it.

Comment: Do you mean `1e8`, i.e. `1 * (10 ** 8)`?

Comment: Thats a good question...I thought it was the letter "l". 1*10^8 is definitely more meaningful.  But how does that affect the y-axis?  the y-axis in the plot has the integers 1, 2, 3, 4...and the dependent values of the function cross the y-axis well below 1.  The values are actually 1 * 10^8 I suppose?

Comment: You can get rid of it with `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset = False)`.

Answer (score 23):

`1e8` is standard scientific notion, and here it indicates an overall scale factor for the y-axis.  That is, if there's a `2` on the y-axis and a `1e8` at the top, the value at `2` actually indicates `2*1e8 = 2e8 = 2 * 10^8 = 200,000,000`.

Note that `exp(20) = 4.85e8` and `exp(3) = 20.1`, and since the first number is too large to conveniently express directly and the second one can be expressed directly, you have the scientific notation in the first and not (explicitely) in the second.

Answer (score 0):

The notation '1e8' in visuals in Python typically represents values using scientific notation. In this case, it means 1 multiplied by 10 to the power of 8, which is 100,000,000. This notation is often used to handle large numbers more conveniently on visualizations, especially when dealing with data that spans a wide range of magnitudes. It helps to maintain clarity in the visualization by expressing values in a compact and standardized form on the tick labels.